# PayPal Website Donation IPN/API

Tags: html, api, paypal, paypal-ipn

So I'm wondering how to create a PayPal Donation IPN/API.
I'm not exactly sure if that is what they are called so here is a screen shot of what I'm talking about.

http://s9.postimg.org/jxixshjan/paypal.jpg (Updated)

Here is the naked input and button only. No lists.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CAD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Example">
<div class="input-prepend" style="display:inline; padding-right:10px;">
<span class="add-on">$</span><input type="text" id="supportAmount" name="amount" value="5.00" style="width:50px;">
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Leave a message to the Developer:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.example.com/index?supporter=true">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.example.com/index">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="#">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="example">
<input type="submit" id="supportbtn" value="Support Me" />
</form>
```

I'm wondering if only with this HTML code, would I be able to put this on my site and once people click "support me" will the donation come to my PayPal account (after the donator filled out the proper Credit Card or PayPal info of course)

I only have a premier account for PayPal as well. And the name="business" value="email@email.com" needs to be my email associated with PayPal to receive the donation correct?

---

If this code does work only with this HTML code am I able to place the...

```
<input type="submit" id="supportbtn" value="Support Me" />
```

anywhere within the   code? (Look for *******)

Like for example between

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CAD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Example">
<div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width:100%;">
<span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount" value="5.00" placeholder="5.00">
<span class="input-group-btn">
*******<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Support Me">*******
</span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Leave a message to the Developer:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="#">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="example">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer this question for you.

The donation button in PayPal can be created on their site.  They give you code to insert that button into your site.  You will then get an email from the donator and it will tell you who donated to your site.

Now I'm not sure exactly what your asking, but if you want the list of people that donated to your site to appear on your website for everyone to view, you would have to set that up in the PayPal Sandbox.  You would also have to make some sort of database that would submit user information to it:

```
$donate = $_POST['custom'];

mysql_query("UPDATE `persons` SET donated='1' WHERE donator='".$donate."'");
```

Basically this is a hidden file that PayPal points to once the information has been paid for.  Paypal will automatically send a file with strings of values of people who have donated to your site.  The code above would then insert that information into my database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know PayPal offers donation buttons but I wan't the user to enter the amount on my website like shown in the picture. Then once they hit "Support Me" it brings them straight to the credit card/paypal checkout, with no need to enter the amount on the PayPal website.

The tables isn't the thing I need I just happened to leave that in the picture.

Comment: Oh well if you want to do that, just set a price "like a dollar" and allow them to enter the quantity.  That's the only other thing that you can do unless you want to have different buy it now buttons.  Hope this helped.

Comment: But what about this code I put in my post above. Would I be able to use it with my email within the name="business" value="my@email.com" section?

Comment: Yes you can put in your information but you can't have the price change unless you do what I said above where the user changes the quantity.